# PyCharm Tensorflow Plot_model cannot work

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I have a problem about showing the plot model by using TensorFlow in **PyCharm**.

I installed `pydot` and `graphviz` from **Python Interpreter** of **Setting** part of **PyCharm**.

Next, I ran the code and got an error which is defined below.

How can I fix it?

Here is my code snippet which is shown below.

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model

# Plot Model
plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)
```

Here is my error which is shown below.

```
ImportError: ('You must install pydot (`pip install pydot`) and install graphviz (see instructions at https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/) ', 'for plot_model/model_to_dot to work.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution :

1 ) Download `graphviz` from https://graphviz.org/download/

2 ) Define the **path** to recognize plot_model from Tensorflow

```
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'C:/Program Files/Graphviz/bin/'
```

3 ) Define plot_model as shown below.

```
# Plot Model
plot_model(model, "model.png" , show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
```